# Where is better to put my custom authentication logic?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I want to add a bit of logic to my authentication in Spring Boot, check if an account have a specific logic, for example if a date in its account is before the current date.

Where is best placed in a custom filter or in UserDetailsService?

If it's in a filter, is better to extends from any spring class?

---

**Explanation**

As you can see bellow I use a custom userDetailsService() to get the users details (`CuentaUser`) in which there are the fields needed for the logic (for example the expiration date). So now I need to add the logic and comes to me two places where I can put it: in UserDetailsServices (throwing an exception if the logic fails) or as a custom filter.

Where is better to put my custom the authentication logic?

This is my actual security configuration:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CuentaRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());

    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return (username) -> accountRepository.findByUsuario(username)
                .map(a -> new CuentaUser(a, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER", "write")))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("could not find the user '" + username + "'"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter csrfTokenFilter = new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter();
        http.addFilterAfter(csrfTokenFilter, CsrfFilter.class);

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();

    }

}
```

Edit: I found that for the example of expiration date, UserDetails have an attribute for it, so is better to use it. Anyway you need to check it with a custom AuthenticationProvider if you don't use the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an AuthenticationProvider and put the login inside it.

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

You can see more here:

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider